# Why do some dates not have any data on the Federal Reserve historical currency data?

Tags: foreign-exchange, historical-data, online-data-source, federal-reserve

Example: https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h10/hist/dat00_al.htm

Some of the days, such as `12-Nov-01`, say `ND` instead of a price. I assume that this means "No Data", but it's not explained anywhere.

Why would some days not have this data? And it's quite a few days, too, if you scroll down the huge table.

If I'm using this to look up how much money was worth for a certain date, should I instead pick the next or previous day? Or maybe some sort of average calculation based on nearby days?

Primarily, I'm asking why some days lack this data to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

It's due to banking holidays.  You need to look at a prior date, or use

In the case of 12 Nov 2001, this was due to Remembrance Day (observed).

Alternatively, don't use the Fed as a source!  The forex markets had active trading on these days.

Cheers,
Richard.

Comment: FYI it's called "Veterans Day" in the US. I only bring it up because that's where the Fed is.